# Play MP3 with loop as variable

Tags: javascript, html

```
x='true';

function play(file){
    document.getElementById('player').innerHTML="<embed src=\""+file+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
```

This code works, but how can I replace `loop=\"false\"` by `loop=x`. I tried various combinations with brackets etc.

Comment: Isn't `loop` a boolean, not an int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=true;

function play(file){
document.getElementById('player').innerHTML="<embed src=\""+file+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"" + x +"\" />";
}
```